# Remote performance monitor Fails to retrieve GC heap

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

Hi*,
I am using the .NET Compact framework Remote Performance Monitor from the .net 3.5 compact framework powertoys.
It is able to run an applications and get statistics from it, but after a while it fails to vieuw the GC heap on the platform with this exception:
http://files.stormenet.be/cfrpm_exc1.JPGhttp://files.stormenet.be/cfrpm_exc2.JPG
I am running WIN CE 6 on a x86 cpu.
Anyone has an idea how to fix this? (or knows an alternative tool ...)
**Edit:** Seems I'm not the only one with [this problem](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=331277). So I guess I should be searching for alternative tools ...

> A call to Microsoft's support comes back with the answer that the Remote
>   Performance Monitor (RPM) for .NETCF 3.5 (and presumably the entire "Power
>   Toys" package that RPM comes with) is not supported by Microsoft. So
>   despite much hype at last year's MEDC conference on these tools, if they
>   don't work for you, your out of luck (at least as far as MS support).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's any consolation, I checked with the CF team and they've finally gotten back to me on this.  They've got it as an open bug and are looking at it.  I take that to mean that it's not you and that there are some circumstances that can cause this (I've never seen it on any device so far).

Comment: I must say, it is an pretty annoying bug for me :)
Thanks for checking with the CF team.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the 2.00 one against it?

I also wouldn't be so swift to point the finger at MS. The issue might be to do with customisations to the OS performed by the OEM.